# Can not run github action

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I created action.yml like that

```
name: PHPUnit 5.6
description: Run your PHPUnit tests with php 5.6 in your Github Actions.
inputs:
  coverage_html:
    description: Generate code coverage report in HTML format
    required: false

  coverage_text:
    description: Generate code coverage report in text format (true to output to console, path to output to file)
    required: false

  coverage_xml:
    description: Generate code coverage report in PHPUnit XML format
    required: false

  args:
    description: Extra arguments to pass to the phpunit binary
    required: false
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: entrypoint.sh
      shell: bash
```

entrypoint.sh

```
docker ps
```

But when action run, i got following error

```
Error: nguyenthemanh2601/phpunit/v1/action.yml (Line: 22, Col: 7): There's not enough info to determine what you meant. Add one of these properties: run, shell, uses, with, working-directory
Error: nguyenthemanh2601/phpunit/v1/action.yml (Line: 22, Col: 7): There's not enough info to determine what you meant. Add one of these properties: run, shell, uses, with, working-directory
Error: System.ArgumentException: Unexpected type '' encountered while reading 'steps item uses'. The type 'StringToken' was expected.
```

I'm trying to follow the [example here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action)
But it's not working

Comment: Did you try adding a step before executing the script with `- run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH` (using shell: bash)? For what I understand, you need to add the action's path to the runner system path (to locate the `entrypoint.sh` script during execution), and run the `entrypoint.sh` script.

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to set the correct path of the script i.e. prefix the script with `$GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/entrypoint.sh` or `${{ github.action_path }}/entrypoint.sh` and also make sure that the script `entrypoint.sh` itself is executable.

Comment: @GuiFalourd i tried adding $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH, $GITHUB_PATH
But still getting a similar error. Even if my action.yml file has only 10 lines left, still getting error at Line: 22, Col: 7.
Is there any caching here? And how can i resolve it

Comment: Line: 22, Col 7 in your `action.yml` file is where you're executing the `- run: entrypoint.sh` step. Adding a previous step to set the action path should at least update the line number. You may have not push the code the default branch to test the action?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I changed action,yml and remove line 10 to end of file. Push it to default branch and action runing. But still getting a similar error: Line: 22, Col: 7

Comment: Is it a public repo? If yes, could you eventually share the url to allow to fork the repo and perform some tests?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thank for your help. This is my repo https://github.com/nguyenthemanh2601/phpunit

Comment: I have made a fork [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/phpunit). The problem was that you where always calling the `@v1` tag in your workflow testing the action. In that case it would be better to use `@main` to be sure to use the version you updated on the default branch. As you can see on the [Actions tab](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/phpunit/actions), the script is being executed as expected now. I'll add an official answer explaining what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the public repository with the action implementation, I identified two issues:

1. To call the script located in the action repository, during the composite action execution, you need to set the `github.action_path` in the `$GITHUB_PATH` (runner system path) for the action to be able to locate the `entrypoint.sh` file.

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      shell: bash
    - run: entrypoint.sh
      shell: bash
```

2. You created a `@v1` tag to test your action in a workflow you configured inside the repository. However, if you don't delete / update the tag every time you update the action, the test will always use the same action implementation / version you generated the first time.  My suggestion if to always use the branch you're using for the implementation to test the workflow, using the `@branch` reference.

Here is an example using the `main` branch:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: <owner>/<repo>@main
```